# click event not working in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new in angular2.I have problem while calling click event.It gives me error. here is my code:

```
<form>
    <input ngControl="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email">
    <input ngControl="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
  <button  (click)="postData()">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Here is My component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/form.component.html'
})
export class FormComponent {
    postData(){}
};
```

It gives me error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
```

Comment: Why didn't you show the contents of `postData()`? That's where the problem is

Comment: Can you try to reproduce with the plunker I added in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess... you probably forgot to to inject the http service into your component's constructor:

```
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
   providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
   ...
})
export class FormComponent {
    constructor(private _http:Http) {}
    postData() {
       this._http.post(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: HTTP_PROVIDER has been replaced with HttpModule